# storing filename and path in variable to use with Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script to find the most recent .bak in a certain directory and copy the file to another location. When I use Get-ChildItem the file name isn't enlcosed in single quotes so when i try to copy it Copy-Item cant find it. ( I think)

```
$dir = 'E:\Backups\'

$dest = 'F:\'

$filename = Get-ChildItem -path $dir -filter *.bak |  Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | select FullName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders

echo @filename

copy-Item -path @filename -destination @dest
```

echo @filename returns E:\Backups\company.bak but i think need 'E:\Backups\company.bak' for it to work?

```
PS C:\Users\prodadmin> copy-Item -path @filename -destination @dest
Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData'.
At line:1 char:1
+ copy-Item -path @filename -destination @dest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

As above, typed it all in one go.

Comment: $filename is an array.  So use : $filename |  foreach { copy-Item -path $_ -destination ($dest + $_)  } You will also need to remove the path since you have Fullname.

Comment: thanks, i changed my filter use 'select Name' instead of 'select FullName' and changed this too $filename | foreach { copy-Item -path ($dir + $_) -destination ($dest + $_) }

sorry for more Qs but absolute novice at this


copy-Item : Cannot find path 'E:\Backups\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData' because it does not exist.

Comment: That won't work since you do not have the Fullname of the source file to copy.  You need both the Fullname and Name.  The Fullname is needed for the source and the name is needed for the destination.  I think the issues was the array which is fixed with the foreach.

Comment: @jdweng No, the code uses `Select-Object -First 1` which means there will be only one item returned, not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get-ChildItem returns `FileInfo` (and also `DirectoryInfo`) **objects**.
- By using `select FullName` you tell PowerShell to return an new object with one property called `FullName` and you lose the `Name` property.
- `Format-Table` is a cmdlet used for **display purposes only**, so never use that on data you want to process further.
- Lastly, you prefix the variables you have with `@` instead of `$`

Try

```
$dir  = 'E:\Backups\'
$dest = 'F:\'

$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.bak' -File |   # do not return directories
        Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |             # or did you mean LastWriteTime (=> last modified date) ?
        Select-Object -First 1                             # return just 1 FileInfo object


Write-Host "Found $($file.Name)"  # write to console

Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $dest
```